# You can't operate on a closed ResultSet using JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

In my Kotlin project I am using JPA with Hibernate to access a MySQL database. In detail I am using the following versions

```
hibernate_version = '5.2.12.Final'
hibernate_validator_version = '6.0.7.Final'
mysql_connector_version = '5.1.46'
```

I should mention that I am also using hibernate-c3p0 for connection pooling.

Every now and then I will get exceptions when running queries likes the following one:

```
api_1          | javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
api_1          |        at dao.ChampionBuildDao.findBuildsForChampionWithFilterDB(ChampionBuildDao.kt:222)
api_1          |        at dao.ChampionBuildDao.findBuildsForChampionWithFilter(ChampionBuildDao.kt:190)
api_1          |        at controller.BuildController.getBuildsForChampion(BuildController.kt:113)
api_1          |        at controller.MainKt$main$2$5.invokeSuspend(main.kt:195)
api_1          |        at controller.MainKt$main$2$5.invoke(main.kt)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:148)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.routing.Routing.interceptor(Routing.kt:29)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:93)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$2.invokeSuspend(CallLogging.kt:130)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$2.invoke(CallLogging.kt)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invokeSuspend(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt:106)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invoke(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invokeSuspend(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:31)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invoke(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt)
api_1          |        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:55)
api_1          |        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:111)
api_1          |        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:160)
api_1          |        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:54)
api_1          |        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.handleRequest(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:22)
api_1          |        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.channelRead(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:16)
api_1          |        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
api_1          |        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
api_1          |        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
api_1          |        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
api_1          |        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
api_1          |        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
api_1          |        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
api_1          |        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
api_1          |        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
api_1          | Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:384)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
api_1          |        ... 50 more
api_1          | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed ResultSet!!!
api_1          |        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
api_1          |        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
api_1          |        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:691)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:987)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
api_1          |        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
api_1          |        ... 59 more
api_1          | Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

which was thrown when running the following code (In the line with the query.resultList):

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@Synchronized
fun findBuildsForChampionWithFilterDB(cacheKey: String, chmpId: Long, patchId: Long, position: Position): List<ChampionBuild2> {
    val query: Query
    when {
        (patchId != -1L && (position == Position.ANY || position == Position.COMPOSITE)) -> {
            // Patch filter
            query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM ChampionBuild2 b WHERE b.champion.chmpid = :chmpid AND b.patch.enabled = true AND b.games >= 6 AND b.patch.patchid = :patchid ORDER BY b.patch.patchid DESC, b.confidenceScore DESC, b.games DESC")
            query.setParameter("patchid", patchId)
        }
        (patchId == -1L && position != Position.ANY) -> {
            // Position filter
            query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM ChampionBuild2 b WHERE b.champion.chmpid = :chmpid AND b.patch.enabled = true AND b.games >= 6 AND b.position = :position ORDER BY b.patch.patchid DESC, b.confidenceScore DESC, b.games DESC")
            query.setParameter("position", position.name)
        }
        (patchId != -1L && position != Position.ANY) -> {
            // Both filter
            query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM ChampionBuild2 b WHERE b.champion.chmpid = :chmpid AND b.patch.enabled = true AND b.games >= 6 AND b.position = :position AND b.patch.patchid = :patchid ORDER BY b.patch.patchid DESC, b.confidenceScore DESC, b.games DESC")
            query.setParameter("position", position.name)
            query.setParameter("patchid", patchId)
        }
        else -> {
            // No filter
            query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM ChampionBuild2 b WHERE b.champion.chmpid = :chmpid AND b.patch.enabled = true AND b.games >= 6 ORDER BY b.patch.patchid DESC, b.confidenceScore DESC, b.games DESC")
        }
    }
    query.setParameter("chmpid", chmpId)
    if (position != Position.COMPOSITE) query.setMaxResults(10)
    val ret: List<ChampionBuild2> = if (position != Position.COMPOSITE) query.resultList as List<ChampionBuild2> else this.filterCompositeList(query.resultList as List<ChampionBuild2>)
    AppLogger.infoLog(tag, "Found ${ret.size} builds for champion ${chmpId} with filter ${patchId} ${position}")
    cache.storeDaoResponse(cacheKey, gson.toJson(ret, Util.listTypeBuilds2))

    return ret
}
```

I initially thought that this Exception might be thrown due to concurrency issues, which is why I made it synchronous using the @Synchronized annotation.

However, I am still experiencing those Exceptions every now and then and I have a very hard time finding out what could be the reasons and how to solve them.

I would be thankful for any kind of help to figure this out or gather more info about the root cause.